# What is the probability of significant t-statistic when performing a t-test with the actual value of the underlying data?

Tags: regression

I am taking the standard normal linear regression assumptions, i.e. $y=\beta x+N(0, \sigma^2)$, and I wanted to check my understanding regarding a t-test. If I performed a t-test against $\beta$, i.e.
$$t = \frac{\hat{\beta}-\beta}{\sqrt{\hat{\sigma}^2(x^Tx)^{-1}}}$$
Then would the probability that I get a significant t-statistic just be my significance level?

Comment: Could you explain what distinction you are making with "the actual value of the underlying data"?  How would a t-test be performed otherwise??

Comment: @whuber That seems to refer to when the true parameter value really is the hypothesized value: $\theta = \theta_0.$

Comment: @Dave Or perhaps it refers to a *post hoc* hypothesis where $\beta$ is set to $\hat\beta$?  The possibility of multiple interpretations dictates caution and indicates we should seek clarification before venturing any answer that could be misunderstood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  It would be relatively easy to check this by simulation, but it's the definition of p value. When the null is true, you will get a significant test statistic *p*% of the time, where p is your choice (usually 5%).

Comment: Thank you! I thought this was the case.

Comment: +1 This is why p-value are $U(0,1)$ under the null hypothesis.